# My Angular project produces errors after copying it from another computer

Tags: angular

> Your global Angular CLI version (7.1.1) is greater than your local
>   version (7.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Error parsing C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projectname\node_modules\webpack- 
sources\package.json: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Error parsing C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projectname\node_modules\webpack-sources\package.json: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at readPackage (module.js:126:52)
at tryPackage (module.js:136:13)
at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:218:20)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:545:25)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projectname\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:9:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)`
```

**As i am new to angular am not able to understand this,So please help me!**

Comment: It's just a warning. You don't *have* to update your version as the two versions are similar.

Comment: Thats ok,But my project is not Serves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore cli warning,

```
1.Delete node_modules and package-lock-json. 
2.npm install.
```

this should solve the problem  if this doesn't solve the problem,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli (add sudo in the start if using Linux)
npm cache clean --force / npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you deleted node_modules and package-lock.json files?? and reinstalled them by npm i???

Comment: yes,on npm install i faces much errors and not installed

Comment: can you remove angular cli installed globally, clear npm cache and reinstall cli??

Comment: Will try..BTW Thanks

Comment: And Step #0: Ensure you are in the appropriate folder. You should be in the folder containing the project's package.json file. Then start with #1 above. Also consider checking your version of npm to ensure it is the appropriate version to work with Angular.

Comment: @AswinKumar reinstalling cli globally and clearing  npm cache should do the work

Comment: It Works Thanks